# AngularJS empty scope value when doing POST to web API causes null object

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using AngularJS to POST a custom .NET object to a web API function. My particular issue seems to be with the properties of this custom object being 'null' or blank.

Sample object:

```
Public Class test
    public property EstimateValue as int32
End Class
```

On my sample aspx page I'm bringing down a 'test' object using a GET call on the web API, and storing it in a $scope variable, by default the EstimateValue property is zero, which I expect since that's the frameworks default value.

The issue is when I delete the value from the textbox bound to that scope property, the json sent by Angular becomes:

```
{"EstimateValue":""}
```

And my POST function on the web API:

```
<HttpPost>
    Public Function UpdateTest(testObj As test) As IHttpActionResult
```

The 'testObj' object is always 'Nothing' (vb.net) or null for you c# guys. However making a simple change to the json:
`"EstimateValue":0` and everything works fine.

I've also tried `"EstimateValue":null` which also fails

I've simplified this scenario for illustration purposes I'm using a much more complex object and function but it gets the idea across.

I've searched everywhere and haven't found anything related to null/blank/empty scope properties causing a blank complex object on a POST request.

Does anyone know why the custom object cannot be parsed properly when the json is an empty string? I would have assumed it should translate an integer to zero if there's no value present, I've tried `<FromBody>` with no luck.

Also the same thing happens on date values, you might say to just insert default values before posting, but this would be a huge effort on a large custom object across several API functions, there must be some way to handle this globally without having to custom code something for the default values when users submit empty fields. I'm new to Angular so I'm hoping there's an easy way to fix this.